# Best solution to perform push notification to device and files upload from application on android device

Tags: android, file-upload, push-notification

I want to create an app which will be used on android device which don't have google services support on it. I want to use that app for diagnostics purpose such like if there is any issue that intimate about same by uploading logs,  perform basic system analysis such as Different h/w working report of device. Perform some operation and upload result based on push notification request etc.
So which sdk or solution will be based to perform this diagnostic task.

Comment: I am also looking for the same solution for the device is not using google services. I want to send a push notification. Have you got any solution on that?

Comment: No response yet from anyone.